# Оставить только строки с английскими символами SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо написать запрос sql что он оставить только строки с английскими символами(словами)
например есть столбец:

```
Италия 
Italy
```

Необходимо , чтобы на выходе осталось

```
Italy
```

Пробовал
`not like '%[а-я]%'` , не работает

Comment: `WHERE word NOT REGEXP '[^a-z]'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ROW('Италия'), ROW('Italy')) AS countries(country) WHERE country NOT REGEXP '[^a-z]';`